# How do I add labels to a third axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If i have this:

```
dd=structure(list(req = c(0, 6.24296787098387e-05, 0.000124859357419677, 
    0.000187289036129516, 0.000249718714839355, 0.000312148393549194
     ), st = c(4.20392459337459, 3.101869731322, 3.05827365904846, 
    2.55875394873998, 1.61722938145694, 0.969328686413803), tt = c(1.66320917439717, 
   1.46619835076717, 1.47423709334019, 1.39210979230404, 1.24099973128753, 
   1.15120693233888), nn = c(2.09771326762665, 1.74025312387583, 
   1.74965887129391, 1.64515722021115, 1.38734468460281, 1.30261082263608
   )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

to plot

```
   ggplot(data =dd, aes(x=req))  + 
    geom_line(aes(y=st), size = .8) 

          fs <- pretty(dd[["req"]])
          pers <- round(1 / fs, 2)
```

i would like to add pers as labels to the third axis (ignoring Inf).
In an ordinary plot, we can use `axis()` function:

```
      axis(3, at = req, labels = pers)
```

How to do this in ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce what you're looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)

fs <- pretty(dd[["req"]])
pers <- round(1 / fs, 2)

ggplot(data =dd, aes(x=req))  + 
  geom_line(aes(y=st , color = "Model spectrum"), size = .8) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 1/., breaks = pers))
```

[image]

Or perhaps slightly tidier:

```r
library(ggplot2)

fs <- pretty(dd[["req"]])
pers <- round(1 / fs, 2)

ggplot(data =dd, aes(x=req))  + 
  geom_line(aes(y=st , color = "Model spectrum"), size = .8) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., labels = pers, breaks = fs))
```

[image]

For tidy labels (from calculated braeks):

```r
ggplot(data =dd, aes(x=req))  + 
  geom_line(aes(y=st , color = "Model spectrum"), size = .8) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 1/., breaks = pers, labels = scales::label_number()))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, can we remove the values after the comma  like  3000  4000   5000 6000 10000

Comment: Yes you can add something like a formatting function `labels = scales::label_number()` to get it to round to 0dp (new example above) or in the second example it will keep the `.33` from ones with decimals and drop the `.00` from ones without.